# Intellij doesn't show runtime errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

When I run my java project, either using "gradle run" or running the Main method from Intellij, if I get an error, the program simply stops executing with "Process finished with exit code 0". For example, if I try to access an array at the wrong index, the program stops and no errors are shown. I tried wrapping in a try statement the code in my main method, but nothing changes.

Comment: which framework are you using? The http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html?is-external=true handles what happens when an exception is caught, and whether or not this is translated to an exit code depends on how you run your program.

Comment: I am not sure, all I did to setup the project was run "gradle init"

Comment: Paste your try-catch code please.